# Method called on render without click react native

Tags: reactjs, button, header, state, native

I am having an issue where a method is being called automatically on render in my react native application. Here are the snippets:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Network',
        headerRight: () => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Button
                title='Invite'
                color='#ccc'
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('InviteUser')}
            />
                <Button
                    title='Search'
                    color='#ccc'
                    onPress={() => navigation.state.params.handleSearch}
                />
            </View>
            ),
    };
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.state = {
        dataSource:[],
    };
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSearch: this.getNearbyUsers(user_id, auth_token)})
}
```

It's happening specifically for the search button. Invite works fine. I am pretty new to RN still, so can anyone give some help please?

Edit* added getNearbyUser():

```
getNearbyUsers(user_id, auth_token) {
    console.log('Get Users: id:' + user_id);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user_id', user_id);
    formData.append('auth_token', auth_token);
    fetch("https://{url}", {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
        //JSON.stringify({'user_id': user_id, 'auth_token': auth_token})//, 'latitude': 33.0296843, 'longitude': -96.7059628})
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            // console.log(responseJson.users[0])
            this.createSearchList(responseJson.users)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Local Network Error: ' + error)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSearch: this.getNearbyUsers(user_id, auth_token)})
```

To

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSearch: () => this.getNearbyUsers(user_id, auth_token)})
```

Comment: I had tried that before, but when I do that the click doesn't work at all.

Comment: If you follow the code I posted, and then for the button OnPress do : onPress={navigation.state.params.handleSearch} does it work?

Comment: I tried that too, and it crashes with error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params.handlerSearch')

Comment: can you post your getNearbyUsers function

Comment: Added it to the original post, I changed the URL so I don't give that info out. Otherwise exactly as I have in code

Comment: can you set it to be an arrow function instead?

Comment: What is an arrow function?

Comment: Ok, did a quick search of what that is, and it seems to have solved it. Thanks